# Is there a way to keep displaying alternative routes on map, drawn using drawRoutes() method, on clicking any of alternative route in mapbox android?

Tags: mapbox

I have displayed a list of direction routes on map, using "draw Routes()" method of Navigation "Mapbox Map" class. I have added start navigation method after it and providing it with first route in list. The navigation route is displayed in blue color and rest all other routes are in gray color, acting as alternative route.

My Query is, as soon as I click on gray color alternative route or nearby position from alternative routes on map, the alternative routes get disappeared. I want to keep displaying the alternative route or else want to disable the click listener on alternative route, so that they don't disappear. Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Please help me out with the same.

Note: added spaces in words mentioned in quotes to avoid typing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are new here and i would like to help you!

Could you please share the code in which you implement the example you describe? It is very helpful for other developers if they can reproduce the behaviour.

This would help a lot, and saves time when trying to answer your question! As a nice side effect, you would not receive negative votes!

Comment: Thanks Moritz, but I am able to resolve it. I have added showAlternativeRoutes(false) in my code, and I achieved my functionality. :)